# Problemas de redirecionamento no menu do wordpress página one-page

Tags: wordpress, menu

Estou utilizando este tema: https://the7.io/business-one-page/

só que meus menus não estão se "comportando" como o do tema nas demais páginas, apenas na página inicial rolando normalmente. Só que nas demais ele não está retornando para a inicial, não consigo encontrar o problema, se está no link, ou alguma outra configuração.

Comment: Jovem sua pergunta está meio confusa. O que não está funcionando? Esse efeito de Scroll é para funcionar só na primeira página mesmo pelo que entendi. Qual erro mais em específico está acontecendo?

Comment: é para funcionar o scroll apenas na primeira página, e está ok. Mas nas demais o menu não está retornando para a inicial, como o exemplo do template